# how to add custom label view to uitextview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am developing one message application in ios for iPhone .
i have one textview in which i have to write name of persons and on input space in uitextview i have to show the previously entered content in different text with different background .let me explain with image!
[image]

can anyone help me how can i achieve this kind of thing in my text view with CROSS MARK and on click of Cross Mark I want to delete that bubble?

so when user inputs the space after write some string in textview then it will convert with following view in green background with cross button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use some type of token field. Search github. Something like [this](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField).

Comment: yes...same ...thanx man...i don't know the proper word for that

Comment: Can u please tell me how can i add cross button or image in that view and on touch of that cross button i want to delete that bubble?

Comment: Look for a different library that provides it or add a button as a subview. Just need the appropriate image and to increase the bubble width.